# How can I figure out what UITableViewCell I'm clicking on during a search?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode4.3, uisearchbar

I have a table view set up with a search bar. Everything works great: when I type text into the search bar, the results update in the table view based on my search text. The problem I'm having is in determining what the ID of the table cell is to pass that along when I'm going to my detail view. To clarify: the cells in the table view are usually generated from a SQLite3 database and ordered by their name. So if I have 4 cells: (Cabernet Cortis, Cabernet Franc, Cabernet Sauvignon and Ruby Cabernet), their IDs are normally (78, 79, 80, 378). However when I search "cabernet", and these four items come up, the indexPath.row is (1, 2, 3, 4) instead of (78, 79, 80, 378) so it's taking me to the wrong grape in the detail view (which are the first four grapes in alpha order as entered into my DB).

Here is some code to help clear things up. I think what would help is if I can obtain the ID of each grape that comes up as a search result and also have an MSMutableArray of those values, and then use `[actualIDNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` instead of just `indexPath.row`.

```
//ViewGrapesViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
- (void) searchGrapesTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfGrapes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResult;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResultID;
@property (nonatomic) Boolean isSearchOn;

//ViewGrapesViewController.m
//synthesize variables, etc
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        //obtain grapes from the DB, etc.
        //add searchNames to an NSMutableArray
        listOfGrapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=1; i<=[self.grapes count]; i++) {
            Grapes *theGrape = [self.grapes objectAtIndex:(i-1)];
            NSString *grapeSearchName = theGrape.searchName;
            [listOfGrapes addObject:grapeSearchName];
        }
        searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        searchResultID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        isSearchOn = NO;

    //search bar stuff
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearchOn = YES;
}

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchText length] > 0) {
        isSearchOn = YES;
        [self searchGrapesTableView];
    }
    else {
        isSearchOn = NO;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) searchGrapesTableView {
    [searchResult removeAllObjects];
    [searchResultID removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *str in listOfGrapes)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0) {
            [searchResult addObject:str];
            //would love to add ID to searchResultID array here, don't know how to do that
        }
    }
}

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self searchGrapesTableView];
}

- (void) searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearchOn = NO;
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//table view code
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //first check if the user is searching
    if (isSearchOn) {
        return 1;
    }
    //if not, then search by alpha order
    else {
        return 24;
    }
}

//create header titles & number of rows in section (it's a lot of code and works fine)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"grapeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //is the user searching?
    if (isSearchOn) {
        NSString *cellValue = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }

    //otherwise...
    else {
        NSInteger theNumber;
        NSInteger numberToAdd = [[howManyRowsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue];
        theNumberToAdd = numberToAdd;
        theNumber = numberToAdd + indexPath.row;

        //cell title = grape name
        Grapes *grape = [self.grapes objectAtIndex:theNumber];
        NSString *theGrapeName = grape.grapeName;
        cell.textLabel.text = theGrapeName;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //is the user searching?
    if (isSearchOn) {
        theNumberToAdd=0; //which is wrong but here for the time being
        //i have to have the ID here in order to do some logic to figure out what row to return
    }

    //otherwise...
    else {
        theNumberToAdd = [[howManyRowsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue]; // i performed this logic elsewhere
    }


    ViewGrapeViewController *detailViewController = (ViewGrapeViewController *)self.presentedViewController;
    detailViewController.detailItem = [self.grapes objectAtIndex: (indexPath.row+theNumberToAdd)];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toGrapeDetail"]) {       
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //is the user searching
        if (isSearchOn) {
            theNumberToAdd=0;  // which is wrong
        }

        //otherwise...
        else {
            theNumberToAdd = [[howManyRowsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue];
        }

        NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row+theNumberToAdd)];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: For example I considered using `NSUInteger index = [self.grapes indexOfObject:str];`, except that it will only return the lowest index, and I know at least for the search term Cabernet there will be 4 IDs I need returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your did select item method, get the text from the cell that was selected and iterate through your array until you find an item that matches, then open that cell's detail view. This only will work if you have all unique item names.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    for (int j=0; j<whateverArray.count; j++)
    {
        NSString *temp = [whateverArray objectAtIndex:j];
        if ([str isEqualToString:temp])
        {
            //do whatever you would do if the user actually clicked the row at position j
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! A lightbulb just went off in my head! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to make a temporary array when a search is carried out, that way you won't need to worry about the cell index. Each time a search is carried out, simply add the results to an empty array. Since you're already looping through the original array to find the results, why not store them (and save yourself from looping through the original array twice)?

Comment: Yep, using content from the cell itself to find the original element is bad practice.  Really you're supposed to maintain a data source for any given table and use the index to determine which one has been selected.

Comment: But so easy. A better solution would be to make a custom cell with an index property and associate the name dictionary with an index dictionary. Then you'd call the load method based on the index property instead of cell location. You could use the tag to do this too, but that could lead to some errors. For a known, dev-supplied dictionary of unique strings there's nothing wrong with this method.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work when you have identical strings.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "This will only work with if you have all unique item names." Because this is a grape-type searching app unique names are explicated... right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a sequential tag number for each cell that correlates to your Array count. Then you grab the tag number and use it for the object at index.

This might be slightly more efficient than searching each string and it would accommodate for duplicate string names.

Code would be in:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionCellIdentifier];
 cell.tag = i //where i increments by one each entry into the function.
 }
```

Comment: I don't see how this will help in figuring out what object I'm looking at from my searchResult array.

Comment: Think of the tags for each cell directly correlating to the array. A 1 for 1 match if you will.

Example [Array objectforindex:1] is equal to a cell.tag = 1. When you are in the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath you get the cell.tag value which should directly correlate to the index in your array with the correct value. Cool?