# Is there some way to store indexes of objects passing a test other than NSIndexSet?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, xcode4.3, nsindexset

I have a table and search bar. The table is generated from a SQLite DB and the search bar searches those objects. The problem I had was when I wanted to know what was the index of the search result, if I just looked at the array of search results and compared to my DB table rows, it couldn't account for duplicate entries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617247/how-can-i-figure-out-what-uitableviewcell-im-clicking-on-during-a-search), so then I implemented a method using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674498/how-can-i-determine-the-index-of-an-object-in-an-nsmutablearray-when-i-search-fo).

The problem now is, I get an NSIndexSet as my result. I want to be able to query this as I can an NSMutableArray but I know it's not possible, so I'm enumerating the IndexSet, which causes significant memory problems as there are over 5,000 possible results. Is there a better way to do this? I need to determine which items are search results, and then which particular result I'm looking at in the table.

```
//when the user searches, this function is called:
- (void) getGrapeMatches {
    numSearchGrapes=0;
    listOfTheGrapeIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *str in listOfGrapes)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0) {
            [searchResult addObject:str];
            numSearchGrapes++;
        }
    }
    BOOL (^test)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop);

    test = ^ (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([searchResult containsObject: obj]) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    };

    //this is the part that takes forever because I have over 5000 items in listOfGrapes
    NSIndexSet *indexes = [listOfGrapes indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:test];
    NSUInteger index=[indexes firstIndex];
    while(index != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index];
        [listOfTheGrapeIDs addObject:tempString];
        index=[indexes indexGreaterThanIndex: index];
    }
}
```

I rely on having `listOfTheGrapeIDs` because it's the way I figure out what item I'm looking at in the table cell later on. I just wish there were an easier way to do this. Let me know if more code is necessary to help in understanding this problem.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand--but can't your database directly return the results of interest using a SQL query? Now you have the objects that match your search term.

Comment: Instead of storing a stringified (?!) version of every index, why not just filter the `listOfGrapes` to only those objects passing the test?

Comment: OK now I'm wondering why I didn't think of using a SQL query ages ago. Brilliant and totally obvious solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: @nielsbot, if you post that as an answer I will vote it up & accept. Thank you so much for posting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reposting as answer:

Not sure I totally understand--but can't your database directly return the results of interest using a SQL query? Now you have the objects that match your search term.